# Importing a module as 2 different modules in Python

Tags: python, import, module

I have a Python file that contains my module, say it's name is `player.py`.
I need to import `player` module in my `main.py` file and create 2 players from the module.

For reasons i can not control, i have to save some information as global
variable (it's a bad practice i know, but there is no other way since i'm not allow to create
class and instantiate object).

Is there a way to import my `player` module as if i import it from 2 different files.

More technically, i want this

```py
# player1 and player2 does not share the same global variables.
import player as player1
import player as player2
```

to be the same as if i make a clone of my `player.py` file and name it `player_clone.py` then
import like this in `main.py`

```py
import player as player1
import player_clone as player2
```

Comment: It sounds like you need a `class`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like someone needs classes.

So in our `player.py` file we will create our class containing `name` and `points`.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,name,points):
        self.name = name
        self.points = points
    def display(self):
        return self.name,self.points
```

In our `main.py` file we will create our objects, `player1`&`player2`.

```
from player import Player
player1 = Player('bob',10)
player2 = Player('joe',20)
print(player1.display())
print(player2.display())
```

output

```
('bob', 10)
('joe', 20)
```

This is the general structure, you can customize it to your likings.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a `class`. For example:

```
class Player:
    hp = 10
    dmg = 5
    
    def take_dmg(self):
        self.hp -= 5
```

Here we have a new `class` named `Player`. Inside I have set two variables, hit-points and damage, and a function to take damage.

Now lets see how to use it.

```
player1 = Player() # This is like a module you can import multiple times to different names
player2 = Player() # but each one is separate from the next, as far as the data inside goes

# print the player hit-points and damage:
print(player1.hp) # just like doing module.function() :)
print(player2.dmg)
# Ouput: 
# 10
# 5

# call the take_dmg function and print hp:
player1.take_dmg()
print(player1.hp)
# Output: 
# 5
```

Also see BuddyBob's answer, mine is more watered down. And make sure you don't forget your good friend google. :)